# com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: Не удалось установить соединение TCP/IP к серверу

Tags: java, sql-server, jdbc

Пытаюсь подключиться к базе данных SQL Server

Вот мой код:

```
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DatabaseMetaData;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.SQLException;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Connection conn = null;

        try {
            conn = DriverManager.getConnection(
                    "jdbc:sqlserver://localhost:1433;DatabaseName=test_new",
                    "thinkpad",
                    "password");

            if (conn != null) {
                DatabaseMetaData dm = (DatabaseMetaData) conn.getMetaData();
                System.out.println("Driver name: " + dm.getDriverName());
                System.out.println("Driver version: " + dm.getDriverVersion());
                System.out.println("Product name: " + dm.getDatabaseProductName());
                System.out.println("Product version: " + dm.getDatabaseProductVersion());
            }

        } catch (SQLException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            try {
                if (conn != null && !conn.isClosed()) {
                    conn.close();
                }
            } catch (SQLException ex) {
                ex.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Получаю вот эту ошибку:

```
"C:\Program Files\Amazon Corretto\jdk1.8.0_265\bin\java.exe" "-javaagent:C:\Program Files\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA 2020.2.2\lib\idea_rt.jar=52820:C:\Program Files\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA 2020.2.2\bin" -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -classpath "C:\Program Files\Amazon Corretto\jdk1.8.0_265\jre\lib\charsets.jar;C:\Program Files\Amazon Corretto\jdk1.8.0_265\jre\lib\ext\access-bridge-64.jar;C:\Program Files\Amazon Corretto\jdk1.8.0_265\jre\lib\ext\cldrdata.jar;C:\Program Files\Amazon Corretto\jdk1.8.0_265\jre\lib\ext\dnsns.jar;C:\Program Files\Amazon Corretto\jdk1.8.0_265\jre\lib\ext\jaccess.jar;C:\Program Files\Amazon Corretto\jdk1.8.0_265\jre\lib\ext\jfxrt.jar;C:\Program Files\Amazon Corretto\jdk1.8.0_265\jre\lib\ext\localedata.jar;C:\Program Files\Amazon Corretto\jdk1.8.0_265\jre\lib\ext\nashorn.jar;C:\Program Files\Amazon Corretto\jdk1.8.0_265\jre\lib\ext\sunec.jar;C:\Program Files\Amazon Corretto\jdk1.8.0_265\jre\lib\ext\sunjce_provider.jar;C:\Program Files\Amazon Corretto\jdk1.8.0_265\jre\lib\ext\sunmscapi.jar;C:\Program Files\Amazon Corretto\jdk1.8.0_265\jre\lib\ext\sunpkcs11.jar;C:\Program Files\Amazon Corretto\jdk1.8.0_265\jre\lib\ext\zipfs.jar;C:\Program Files\Amazon Corretto\jdk1.8.0_265\jre\lib\jce.jar;C:\Program Files\Amazon Corretto\jdk1.8.0_265\jre\lib\jfr.jar;C:\Program Files\Amazon Corretto\jdk1.8.0_265\jre\lib\jfxswt.jar;C:\Program Files\Amazon Corretto\jdk1.8.0_265\jre\lib\jsse.jar;C:\Program Files\Amazon Corretto\jdk1.8.0_265\jre\lib\management-agent.jar;C:\Program Files\Amazon Corretto\jdk1.8.0_265\jre\lib\resources.jar;C:\Program Files\Amazon Corretto\jdk1.8.0_265\jre\lib\rt.jar;C:\Users\besto\Desktop\spring-in-action-5-samples\ch05\untitled\target\classes;C:\Users\besto\.m2\repository\com\microsoft\sqlserver\mssql-jdbc\7.0.0.jre8\mssql-jdbc-7.0.0.jre8.jar" Main
com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: Не удалось установить соединение TCP/IP к серверу localhost по порту 1433. Ошибка: "connect timed out. Проверьте свойства соединения. Убедитесь, что на сервере запущен экземпляр SQL Server и он принимает TCP/IP-соединения по порту. Убедитесь, что TCP-соединения по этому порту не блокируются брандмауэром.".
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException.makeFromDriverError(SQLServerException.java:226)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException.ConvertConnectExceptionToSQLServerException(SQLServerException.java:277)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SocketFinder.findSocket(IOBuffer.java:2379)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.TDSChannel.open(IOBuffer.java:652)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.connectHelper(SQLServerConnection.java:2379)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.login(SQLServerConnection.java:2042)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.connectInternal(SQLServerConnection.java:1889)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.connect(SQLServerConnection.java:1120)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver.connect(SQLServerDriver.java:700)
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:664)
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:247)
    at Main.main(Main.java:13)

Process finished with exit code 0
```

TCP/IP включен
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: А если по IP (127.0.0.0.1)?

Comment: jdbc:sqlserver://127.0.0.0.1:1433; не получилось

Comment: А SQL Server Managment Studio нормально подключается? Запущена ли служба сервера, и служба агента?

Comment: да,  SQL Server Managment Studio работает нормально